# Access an iOS configuration profile from React Native?

Tags: react-native, configuration-profile

I have a React Native application running on my iPhone and I would like to change the app configuration (targeting another environment) when a specific configuration profile is installed.

How can I read/access an iOS configuration profile from a React Native application?

Answer (score 0):

You can make simple custom module to get that value from iOS native side.
Here is the custom module named **RNConfig**

**RNConfig.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "React/RCTBridgeModule.h"

@interface RNConfig : NSObject<RCTBridgeModule>

@end
```

**RNConfig.m**

```
#import "RNConfig.h"

@implementation RNConfig

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

- (NSDictionary *)constantsToExport
{
  NSString* platform_name = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] valueForKey:@"PlatformName"];
  return @{ @"PlatformName": platform_name };
}

@end
```

With **React Native** you can use that module by following code snippets.

```
const { RNConfig } = require('NativeModules');
let platformName = RNConfig.PlatformName;
```

This module could be used when you have multiple targets on iOS side.
So On React Native side, you have many config values according to every targets.

**config/index.js**

```
import { targetA } from './targetA';
import { targetB } from './targetB';

const variables = {
  targetA,
  targetB
};

const { RNConfig } = require('NativeModules');
export default variables[RNConfig.PlatformName];
```

If your iOS target name is **targetA** or **targetB** then you can use the specific configuration setting on React Native side by getting iOS platform name like above.

*Anyway, you can get any types of configuration values on iOS side by changing the **RNConfig.m** file.*

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you know a documentation page where I can find all the available keys I can get the value from the RNConfig.m file? Or are they coming from the custom profile?

Comment: It is the dictionary from the **Info.plist** file.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1413477-infodictionary?language=objc

Comment: Okay so your solution is not about to access a phone profile, right? Or did I misunderstood it?

Comment: It can be used when you want to use the different environment for every Targets on iOS app. With above method you can access the **Info.plist** file for each target. so if you make the different **Info.plist** file for each target(it is possible and you should do that if you have many targets) and you can access each info file with above method.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'm talking about iOS Configuration Profiles (like it is described in this article : https://www.howtogeek.com/253325/how-to-create-an-ios-configuration-profile-and-alter-hidden-settings/)

Comment: Oh, okay. I misunderstood your question. so you mean something like this one? https://www.appconfig.org/ios/

Comment: I mean exactly this : https://developer.apple.com/enterprise/documentation/Configuration-Profile-Reference.pdf

Comment: I think you can access to configuration profiles with like this. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/sc2279/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: so you can use the **Settings** https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/settings

Comment: Sorry I don't how Settings is linked to iOS Configuration Profiles 